# JAVA JSONObject parsing issue

Tags: java, json

I am using `JSONObject` to parse nested JSON from an API example:

```
 {"results":[{"congress":"112","state":"NJ","num_results":"2","offset":"0","members": [{"id":"L000123","first_name":"Frank"..........................
```

I am having trouble accessing the members nested area using `JSONObject`.
This is my code, any thoughts?

```
url= new  URL("http://api.nytimes.com/svc/politics/v3/us/legislative/congress/112/senate/members.json?&state=NJ&api-key=7967107ef3c9e8d6c2f560027f87904e:17:65990356");                


            ByteArrayOutputStream urlOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            IOUtils.copy(url.openStream(), urlOutputStream);
            String urlContents = urlOutputStream.toString();

            // parse the JSON object returned
            JSONObject jsonO = new JSONObject(urlContents);
            System.out.println(jsonO.toString());
            JSONObject results =  jsonO.getJSONObject("results");
            JSONObject  senators = results.getJSONObject("members");
```

Comment: I have not tried your code because i don't have your json library at hand. But it seems results represents a json array, the element of which has property `members`. The array itself doesn't hava that property.

Comment: So how would I go about accessing it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If i correctly find the api of the library you are using, there is a method `getJSONArray` that will give you a `JSONArray` object instead of the gereral `JSONObject`. Then you can use the indexer method `get` to get each element of the array. in this case, you might only want the zeroth element.

Comment: I tried using JSONArray results =  jsonO.getJSONArray("results"); but then how do I access "members" and get their "first_name"s ?

Comment: i've made a mistake. you have to use `getJSONObject(int)` to get an indexed JSONObject. So, results.getJSONObject(0) will give you the first element of results, which is a JSONObject on which you can call `getJSONArray("members")` to retrieve the members array. Now you know how to operate on JSONArrays and JSONObjects and will be able to get to arbitrarily depth in the whole json object

Comment: finally, when you got the actual member, you can call `getString("first_name")` to get one's first name. What's important here it that you have to know what type a certain value is of. There could 3 cases, a value could be another complex json object, a json array, or just plain text. Depending on that you call getJSONObject, getJSONArray of getString.

Comment: System.out.println(results.getJSONObject(0)); gives an error saying that JSONObject can only be applied to Strings not ints.

Comment: so is [this](http://www.json.org/java/) the library you are using?

Comment: Yes I am using the JSONArray and JSONObject libs.

Comment: i tried the code and it compiles ok. would you check your `result` variable is of type JSONArray, and there is method `getJSONObject(int)` defined on JSONArray class in the source code, as suggested by their API?

Comment: Thank you very much that solved everything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  should use third party library like GSON.

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/